# compare two elements of the same class instance variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, compare

It would be very basic but I'm newbie to rails please help.
I've some results in class instance variable called @product. I want to compare two product results. @product has several ids. I want to compare successive ids.Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
<% @products.results.each do |result|
    bid=Brand.where("id=?",result.brand_id)
    bid1=Brand.where("id=?",result+1.brand_id)  %>
    <% if (bid==bid1) %>
       do something
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm not getting the result. Please guide me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Could you post the definitions or explain a bit more about the relationship among your `Product`, `Result` and `Brand` models?

Comment: @amesee  products.results has many brand_ids like 1,23,23,20 etc. I want to compare two brandids at a time. Since I'm using products.each how to compare the two results??For example from the above code during 1st iteration bid=1. In the same iteration I want to compare bid with bid1(variable which stores next brand id. In this case bid1=23). How to do this??

Answer (score 0):

From your code it's very unclear what were you trying to do, but there's quite a few things wrong.  One by one:

If you want to do all of that in the view, you'd need to add ERB tags `<% %>` to lines 2 and 3 as well, otherwise they won't be interpreted as ruby code and will just be printed as html.

It's not usually a good idea to have so much logic in your view - much better would be to do the comparison in the model or even the controller if necessary.

`result+1.brand_id` will throw an error as '1' doesn't have the the method 'brand_id'.  Presumably you want to do `result.brand_id + 1`.

Instead of `Brand.where("id=?",result.brand_id)`, you can do `Brand.find(result.brand_id)`

Comment: products.results has many brand_ids like 1,23,23,20 etc. I want to compare two brandids at a time. Since I'm using products.each how to compare the two results??

Answer (score 0):

You can use "include?" ruby method instead

Just store all the ids in array and then as showed in example do following:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
a.include?(1)   #=> true
a.include?(4)   #=> false
```

for more details please follow below link:

http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<% arr = @products.results.all %>
<% arr.shift %>
<% @products.results.each_with_index do |result,i| %>
    <% bid=result.brand %>
    <% if (bid==arr[i]) %>
       do something
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First put your results into an array, so perhaps in the controller something like:

```
@results = @product.results
```

Then in the view:

```
<% @results.each_with_index do |result, index|
  <% if result.brand_id == @results[index.next].brand_id %>
    # do something
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```